# Найдите факториал числа а. NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

```
section .text
global _start
_start:

mov bx, [a]
call proc_fact
add ax, 30h
mov [fact], ax

mov edx,len
mov ecx,msg
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 0x80
mov edx,1
mov ecx,fact
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4
int 0x80

mov eax,1
int 0x80
proc_fact:
cmp bl, 1
jg do_calculation
mov ax, 1
ret

do_calculation:
dec bl
call proc_fact
inc bl
mul bl
ret

section .data
a db 3
msg db 'Факториал равен:',0xa
len equ $ - msg

section .bss
fact resb 1
```

Для трех работает, как сделать его для всех чисел?
компилятор https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-assembler-nasm-online/

Comment: попробуйте увеличить переменную "fact" как минимум до 4-байт - `fact resd 1`

Comment: тогда в ответе будет "H" для a=4

Comment: Правильно. Факториал 4 = 24. Вы получаете символ "Н", код которого 48h. Если перед сохранением не прибавлять в АХ 30h, то получим 18h=24d. Другими словами, сейчас у вас  вывод чисел только от 0 до 9, а нужен алгоритм вывода 2 и более значных чисел.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: я понимаю, что мне именно этот алгоритм нужен, и не только здесь, а как его сделать? можете код кинуть для примера

Comment: я под винду на фасме прогаю, а как в линухе не знаю.